# Am I writing a good login system?

Tags: databases, account-security, session-management

I am designing a login system for my React app.

All user data must be protected in case of a db leak. I only store encrypted data, with the exception of the email.

To encrypt I need a key and I don't have a place to store keys and storing them in the db would be dumb. So I'm making keys out of the user's email and password. If the user provides the same email and password, the same key will be generated.

Should I even be encrypting the data? I'm storing things like addresses, phone numbers, and some company ID numbers.

Comment: *"I am very confused"* - me too, from reading your question. The question basically describes some (probably incomplete) technical design, without explaining what you want to achieve at the end and why you decided to do it this way. For example it is unclear for me, why do you decided to encrypt various information, including the already hashed password. But the design decisions for the other parts of the question are unclear too.

Comment: I encrypted the data so in case of a database leak all the information in the database is unreachable without the user's password, and included the user email to the key as a fixed salt, so people with the same password don't have the same key. I encrypted the hashed password for no reason really, I could take that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password in plaintext is used to verify the user is who they say they are. You verify them once and give them a new but temporary secret (session secret).

Your question is about the whole login system which there are many other considerations to solve. I think you need a mature library for your language of choice. Or look at auth0.

For the parts you’re asking about - first look at the parts of the system you have to trust with the password.

User, browser, server.

These parts you don’t trust with the password. Network, database, backups.

The goal is to verify the user with their password and exchange that for a temporary token stored in a cookie on the browser.

We don’t trust the browser is forever safe but it should be for a day or whatever risk level you choose.

Then the question is why are you encrypting other stuff on the database with a key derived from the password? Do you not trust the app server to get a key to decrypt data? You trust the app server to process the password.  So don’t set the secret from the ow.

If your threat model is the data should only be accessed by the user with the password then we aren’t talking about a login system but a data privacy system which is totally different.